# Not firing mixpanel-ruby events when running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, mixpanel

I'm using the [mixpanel-ruby](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-ruby) library to send analytics events. The tracker is defined in an initialiser:

```
require 'mixpanel-ruby'
$mixpanel = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(Figaro.env.mixpanel_token)

if Rails.env.development? 
  # Silence local SSL errors
  Mixpanel.config_http do |http|
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  end
end
```

In my controllers I fire events like this:

```
def resume
  @study.resume!
  redirect_to studies_url, notice: 'Study resumed'
  $mixpanel.track(current_user.id, 'Resume study')
end
```

This works well however the events are getting fired when I run the test suite with `rspec spec`, which is not ideal as it eats into my monthly event allowance, not to mention skews the data.

How can I prevent these from firing in the test environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a proxy (puffingbilly, etc.) to simulate the mixpanel service or configure with a custom consumer like

```
$mixpanel = if Rails.env.test?
    Mixpanel::Tracker.new(Figaro.env.mixpanel_token) do |type, message|
        # You can just discard the track in here if you'd like, or you can
        # put it somewhere if you want to test your tracking
        # track_log << [type, message]
    end
else
    Mixpanel::Tracker.new(Figaro.env.mixpanel_token)   # Use the default if we're not testing
end
```

from https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-ruby/issues/35